# How do I split $w = \sin (z + i)$ into real and imaginary parts?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I know that $\sin z= \dfrac{e^{iz}-e^{iz}}{2i}$ but with the (+i) my mind froze.

your support is very appreciated, Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative to the first answer: $\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$, therefore $\sin (z+i)=\frac{e^{i(z+i)}-e^{-i(z+i)}}{2i}$. now you can simplify the formula to obtain the result.

Answer (score 2):

First you should use $\sin(A+B)$:

$$\sin(z+i) = \sin z \cos i + \cos z \sin i$$

Now use $$\cos(z) = \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}\\
\sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$